# Is php's `filemtime` a good idea for Browser Caching or Cache Busting?

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache

I'm using php's `filemtime` to add a version to files, is it a good idea?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css?v=<?=filemtime("./css/custom.css")?>"/>
<script src="js/custom.js?v=<?=filemtime("js/custom.js")?>"></script>
```

This shows up in source like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css?v=1564681659"/>
<script src="js/custom.js?v=1564599819"></script>
```

Is putting a `?v` or a `?ver` the same?

P.S: I'm doing the same to .js & css files, bootstrap, jquery etc. (all local ones only though).

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out various ways to break the cache when you modify a file's contents, but not its name, just use a different filename. That's it. That's literally it. This is how it's supposed to work. Everything just magically falls into place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [HTML5 ★ Boilerplate Docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20120215111417/http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/Version-Control-with-Cachebusting/):

> What is ?v=1" '?v=1' is the JavaScript/CSS Version Control with
>   Cachebusting
>
> Why do you need to cache JavaScript CSS? Web page designs are getting
>   richer and richer, which means more scripts and stylesheets in the
>   page. A first-time visitor to your page may have to make several HTTP
>   requests, but by using the Expires header you make those components
>   cacheable. This avoids unnecessary HTTP requests on subsequent page
>   views. Expires headers are most often used with images, but they
>   should be used on all components including scripts, stylesheets etc.
>
> How does HTML5 Boilerplate handle JavaScript CSS cache? HTML5
>   Boilerplate comes with server configuration files: .htacess,
>   web.config and nginx.conf. These files tell the server to add
>   JavaScript CSS cache control.
>
> When do you need to use version control with cachebusting?
>   Traditionally, if you use a far future Expires header you have to
>   change the component's filename whenever the component changes.
>
> How to use cachebusting? If you update your JavaScript or CSS, just
>   update the "?v=1" to "?v=2", "?v=3" ... This will trick the browser
>   think you are trying to load a new file, therefore, solve the cache
>   problem.

That being said, you can use various things for version to the files. Using `filemtime` is a fine way to do that. I believe it is one of the most mainstream ways I've seen people use. You can leave it and know it will always work correctly and there will be no collisions anytime soon. I am not aware to be any difference between `?v` and `?ver`, but `?v` is the one that is used in 90% of the cases I've seen, maybe more. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what do you mean by there will be no collisions `anytime soon`?

Comment: @RobotBoy It's a figure of speech. You should not worry about this. By using the timestamp, you can make sure it will be always a higher number, than the previous without really doing anything complicated.

Comment: What about the performance? any IO bottleneck because of this and having many many users?